# What's the standard that the ShellCheck refers to?

Tags: shell, shellcheck

Just as the title, I am starting using ShellCheck as a static tool to analyze and help to imrove the shell script, and I am asked a question about the standard this tool referring to to carry out the scan work and the output that based on.
I googled it and expected to see the standard is from Google, Redhat, or Linux community, or even Mirosoft(I know this would be funny if it's true), or anyt tech giant, but I haven't found any clues, so could any one share with me these information?

Comment: Since ShellCheck can check scripts in a variety of language (zsh for instance), most of them not being formally "standardized", it does not make much sense to ask for a standard. I would expect that for _sh_  scripts, the shell defined in POSIX.1-2017 is used as a reference.

Comment: @user1934428 Thank you first for your comment. I agree with you on the point that script language varies, but just like what you've mentioned in the example, 'zsh' is a script language, and it has its own syntax, thus the syntax could be a standard. Let's take your point as a new start and break the original question down, are there standards for each of the script language supported by ShellCheck, e.g. zsh, bash?

Comment: Depends on which zsh version you are refering to. Over the lifetime, several features and language constructs have been added. Same with bash. Early bash did not have associative arrays for instance. Especially with zsh, I was bitten several times when porting my scripts to a newer version, and my old scripts did not run anymore ....

Comment: @user1934428 Haha, I can understand the feeling of that one development only works for one version. That's bad indeed. Thank you for your input.

Comment: If you are talking about messages like "egrep is non-standard" then it's referring to POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard. It's based on its authors' opinions which are [documented on its website](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/).

Comment: Thank you for the first answer. If it all has based the author's/contributor's opintions, how could we say the author's/contributor's opinions are all correct? Maybe it sounds unnecessary that the endorsement is needed, but I think this could be more convincing.

Comment: They aren't "correct", they are opinions. (Their documentation makes justifications for them.)

Comment: Thank you for the further comment. I found Google and Gitlab is using it to check shell, this is convincing enough.